# Trouble Installing php-mysql from webtatic

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum, repository

I have a fresh instance on EC2 of "Linux/Unix, CentOS 6 | 64-bit Amazon Machine Image (AMI)"

This is what I did to get it running.

```
yum install wget 
wget http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm 
sudo rpm -Uvh latest.rpm
yum repolist
yum update

sudo yum install httpd mod_ssl
sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl start
chkconfig --levels 235 httpd on

vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
// add -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
// add -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
/etc/init.d/iptables restart

sudo yum install php54w php54w-mysql php54w-gd php54w-xml php54w-xmlrpc php54w-mbstring php54w-mcrypt php54w-pdo php54w-soap
```

When I get to the final command it fails because:

```
Error: mysql55-libs conflicts with mysql-libs-5.1.67-1.el6_3.x86_64
Error: Package: php54w-mcrypt-5.4.13-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit)
```

I tried not installing php54w-mcrypt, but php54w-mysql still fails. If I try installing php-mysql (not php54w) it still fails.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

**Edit:** Is there an alternate repo to webtatic I can use that has the latest stable releases, that *does* work? Yum base doesn't include php 5.4, which I'd like to use.

Comment: Curious what the solution is, but for now, decided to go with remi. If anyone has an insight into how to resolve this I'd still be very interested.

Answer (score 1):

As Electrawn mentions, the libmcrypt package is now in the Webtatic repo, it was depending on the EPEL repository, but not everyone has this installed.

As for the php54w-mysql installing MySQL 5.5 issue, this was resolved 6th May:
http://www.webtatic.com/news/2013/05/latest-updates-php-5-4-14-5-3-24/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, and sent an email to Andy who runs the webtatic repository. The libmcrypt missing dependency is now included in webtatic repo.

Turnaround on the email was 16 hours.

Comment: just a correction on that turnaround, 7 hours turnaround from your email.

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this issue installing php??w-mysql, try the following instead:

```
yum install php??w-mysqlnd
```

This will skip the dependency check.